# update variables from service when they change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service to get my config settings from the db. I use this service to display various configs throughout the app. The problem I am facing is when I go to the configs page to update the configs the variables don't update until I refresh the page.

SERVICE:

```
app.factory('dataShare', function($rootScope, $log, $q, $http, Data) {

  var configs= {};

      configs.getconfigs=function(){

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        Data.get('config').then(function(data){

          deferred.resolve(data.data);

        });

          return deferred.promise;

      }

    return configs;

});
```

CONTROLLER:

```
app.controller('authCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $log, $location, $http, dataShare) {
  dataShare.getconfigs().then(function(data){
    $scope.configs = data;
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-2"><span ng-if="configs[0].button_name"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info navbar-btn" ng-href="{{configs[0].button_url}}">{{configs[0].button_name}}</a></span></div>
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Is `data.data` actually an array of objects? Or is it just an object like: `{button_name:"somename"}`

Comment: Nothing shown here how you do any updates. A demo would help

Comment: If it is an object then take off the `[0]`, it should just be `configs.button_name`, `[0]` implies you are trying to access an array

Comment: I have resolved the issue by switching from $scope.configs... to $rootScope.configs...

Comment: Were you not calling `dataShare.getconfigs()` after coming back from your config screen?

Answer (score -1):

You can put a "Watch" on the config object.
To do this  , post first initialization of "config" register it to the watch service in the following manner : 
    $scope.config={};
    $scope.$watch('config', function() {
        alert('Config is updated');
        //Do whatever you want to do when config gets updated
    });
    //Service call

You can read more about it over here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

EDIT : 
After going over the issue one more time , I think getting the updates on the "config" is not the issue you are facing.

If your problem is that your view is not updated even though the model is updated , you will have to use the $apply method :

```
dataShare.getconfigs().then(function(data){
    $scope.configs = data;
    $scope.$apply();
  });
```

This would force the angular view to reflect the updated model.

Comment: Do I put this in the controller for in the service

Comment: I had to step away. I will try this when I am back on my computer

Comment: Note you do not need `$scope.$apply` when using an Angular promise service like `$q` (which OP ends up using) the only exception I believe is when doing unit testing where you have to explicitly start a digest. Actually calling it will probably throw a digest already in progress error

Comment: Patrick Evans is right. Read this on `$scope.$apply` http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html Much of the time angular is running the digest cycle automatically.